# Associating existing Annotation to more than one entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Say, organisation has an attachment document. Can I associate this attachment to parent organisation via plugin?

I know another annotation can be created for parent record and file attachment can be copied there. But I'd like to avoid storing copies of attached file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, copying is your only option to have the annotation appear in both records.

The way Annotations are designed completely blocks this reasonable possibility. The Annotation "has-a" Object, even though in forms Objects are presented as the parent of Annotation. So we're stuck with the duplication.

[image: AnnotationBase Info]

You could always write your own microsoft-unsupported schema scripts and a web resource form control... Be sure to share with the community if you do :)

Comment: Thanks! I think we won't use this attach feature and use sharepoint for file sharing instead.